# Function that gets it numerical input from another function that should give an error if the number is negative

Tags: python-3.x, input, error-handling

I am making a function sum() that is supposed to get a positive integer x from the funtion number(). The function number() should give an error if the input is negative and ask the user for another input.

```
def number():
    try:
        x = int(input('Please enter a positive number: '))
        if x <= 0:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print('Could you please enter positive number once againg!!')
        x = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    return x

def sum(x):
    print(f'Your number is {x}')

x = number()
sum(x)
```

I tried to run it, when I give it a negative value it asks again, but if I give it a negative number again something goes wrong. Any idea?

```
Please enter a positive number: -4
Could you please enter positive number once againg!!
Enter a positive number: -4
Your number is -4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what your code does. Try stepping through your function (either by hand or with a debugger), and you will see that this is exactly what is expected. To make the code keep asking until a positive number is obtained, you would need a while loop.

Also, it is not necessary to raise an Error since you catch it immediately after. Your code is actually equivalent to:

```
def number():
    x = int(input('Please enter a positive number: '))
    if x <= 0:
        print('Could you please enter positive number once againg!!')
        x = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    return x
```

Comment: Ok, I overcomplicated it. Thanks!